# What's the maximum number of ribbons a Pokémon can attain in Gen IV?

Tags: pokemon-fourth-generation

Using only Diamond, Pearl, Platinum, HeartGold and SoulSilver, what is the maximum number of ribbons a single Pokémon can legitimately attain?

Don't include Pokémon traded from other games (e.g. Emerald or any Pokémon spinoff games other than the ones listed), event-only ribbons, or ribbons that cannot legitimately appear together on the same Pokémon without cheating.

Don't include the one ribbon that appears on some event Pokémon; **but:** for a bonus point, do any event Pokémon come with more than one ribbon?

Comment: The entire point of the Classic Ribbon is to prevent event Pokemon from being traded on the GTS, so it makes sense to only have one per event Pokemon.

Comment: I believe that means you get the Ponus Boint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ribbon):

You can get 40 in the 4th gen games (w/o trading):

- (4th gen) [Sinnoh Champ ribbon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Ribbons_in_the_games#League_Ribbons)
- 20 contest ([Cool, Beauty, Cute, Smart, and Tough](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Ribbons_in_the_games#Sinnoh_Super_Contest_Ribbons)) ribbons
- 6 [Battle Tower ribbons](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Ribbons_in_the_games#Tower_Ribbons)
- 7 [Weekday ribbons](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Ribbons_in_the_games#Memorial_Ribbons) (from the Day-of-the-week Siblings)
- [Footprint ribbon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Ribbons_in_the_games#Memorial_Ribbons) (max happiness)
- 3 [Sinnoh Resort Area ribbons](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Ribbons_in_the_games#Memorial_Ribbons) (you need 1 Pokemon in your party with at least 10 ribbons to enter the Ribbon Society)
- [Legend ribbon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Ribbons_in_the_games#Memorial_Ribbons) (beat Red)
- (Cross-gen) Effort Ribbon (max EVs)

Comment: I'd count the Effort Ribbon, since it can be obtained in Gen IV. I'm only excluding ribbons which you can't get without trading a Pokémon from Gen III (e.g. Champion Ribbon from Hoenn).